# attempt to index upvalue 'plr' (a nil value)

Tags: lua

**i have tried to fix the error but it didnt work plrase try help me fix it
heres the script:**

```
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer

    local items =game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").Items

    game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").ClientPlaced.OnServerEvent:connect(function(player, itemName, location)

        local itemTemplate = items:FindFirstChild(itemName)


        if (itemTemplate) then
            local item = itemTemplate:clone()
            item.Parent = workspace:FindFirstChild(plr.Name .. "Base").ItemHolder
            item:SetPrimaryPartCFrame(location[1])
        end

    end)
```

Comment: Please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells you that your local variable `plr` is `nil` within the scope of the function you define. So you may not index it inside the function.

```
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer
```

`game.Players.LocalPlayer` is obviously `nil`

`plr.Name` causes the error.

As the function has a `player` argument this is most likely the variable you want to index. But I cannot know for sure as you don't provide all information.

Try `player.Name` instead